# open hyperlink in a new tab in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to put a download link into a column of my table and use it by a "Download" button.

If somebody clicks the button, a new tab will be opened according to the download link.

My problem is, when I use the code below, it opens a new tab, but instead of going to the link, it adds my website before the real link.

How can I fix this?

```
<a target="_blank" href=" ('.$row['download'].') "  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ">
    Download Link
</a>
```

for example, I put `youtube.com`, after opening a new tab instead of going to `youtube.com`, it goes to `mywebsite/youtube.com`

anybody can help me?

Comment: What is the output of `$row['download']`

Comment: it is the download link taken from database, the column name is download.

Comment: Can you please update your question to include an example (copy/paste) of the outputted HTML for this snippet? Use `View Source` in your browser to copy it.

Comment: I want the real actual output, do a `var_dump()` or what @MagnusEriksson said.

Comment: Why are you adding parentheses around the link in your `href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using relative paths instead of absolute paths.

So assuming `$row['download']` gives you `youtube.com` for instance. You need to specify in the `href` attribute of the `a` tag that it is pointing to another website and *not* to a page in your website (relative to the page you're on).

I believe you just need to add `"http://www."` before the name of the website:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.'.$row['download'].'"  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ">Download Link</a>
```

For more information, you can read [this article](https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) on absolute and relative path links.

Comment: Can you try outputting just `$row['download']`?

Comment: Yes, remove the spaces, `(` and `)`. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: You need to test what's coming from the server before using it in your website. Can you tell me what is the exact value of `$row['download']`?

Comment: $row['download'] is youtube.com when i clicked it it came out "http://www.example.com/(www.youtube.com)"

Comment: Do you want to link to youtube.com or stay on the website?

Comment: @FortunatusGathot, If `$row['download']` is equal to `"youtube.com"` then using `href="http://www.'.$row['download'].'"` in your code should work.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, it works perfectly, i use your correction: href="http://'.$row['download'].'" and it works perfectly

Comment: @FortunatusGathot, happy to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify http:// or https:// before download url

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://('.$row['download'].') "  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ">Download Link</a>
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses. There's no reason for them

Comment: That's what is making `%28` and `%29` in the URL.